# Problem after installing LAMP in ubuntu

Tags: apache2, lamp

after installing apache2 It show message like this

Index of /
[ICO]   Name    Last modified   Size    Description
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

how to install this properly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some content. Create file /var/www/html/index.html and put some content in it.

Comment: What Content want to add into that ?

Comment: Your server is working OK, it just doesn't have content to serve - web pages, images, etc. To test whether this is the case create file `/var/www/html/index.html` with a single line: `hello world` and try it with your browser. If you see `hello world' in your browser then apache is working fine and you just need to add the content you want served by Apache.

Comment: But in /var/www/ no html directory

Comment: Have you changed your [DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/urlmapping.html) configuration option?

Comment: Now localhost Option working fine (i.e) Apache server running now
,after installing the php I tried to run localhost/sample.php
But it showing like this

Not Found

The requested URL /testphp.php was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80